# what the best way to make a loop infinite in c++

Tags: c++, loops

in c++ what is  the bets way to make an infinite loop using  the for loop method?

Comment: The classic method:`for (;;) {}` There are probably some duplicates at SO.

Comment: `for(;;) {}`  should do the trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Endless loop in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186809/endless-loop-in-c-c)

Answer (score 2):

These are some ways through which you can make infinite loops -

1. ```
    while(1) {
        ..... statements ....
    }
   ```
2. ```
    while(true) {
        .... statements ......
    }
   ```
3. ```
    for(;;) {
        .... statements ......
    }
   ```
4. ```
    do {
        .......statements.....
    } while(true);
   ```

Comment: Please, consider mentioning that a truely infinte loop would have Undefined Behavior, according to the standard.

Comment: @Bob__  - it's actually an infinite loop without side effects  (or more accurately, such a loop that can't be proven to terminate i.e. be finite) that has undefined behaviour.    A fair few experts would have trouble explaining that coherently;  beginners even less so.

Comment: @Peter: And your comment too is showing how hard it is - the problem for the Standard is that statements like "can't be proven" are not implementable. Do compilers need a theorem prover? How good would they need to be?

Comment: @MSalters - quite so.  I don't claim to be able to fully explain the concern either.   The point in my previous comment is that Bob__ had suggested this answer be modified to comment on something that is actually a fairly difficult corner of C++ (as well as being beyond what the question sought).

Answer (score 0):

It's surprisingly difficult, although the request is also surprisingly illogical. Empty infinite loops are *undefined behaviour* in C++.

See [Optimizing away a "while(1);" in C++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592557/optimizing-away-a-while1-in-c0x/3593551#3593551)

Really though such a thing is unnecessary - simply terminate your program instead. In a sense that is equivalent to having a program that consumes no input and outputs nothing, running forever.