# Is there any advantage to using for loop with no conditions (for (;;)) instead of a while(true) in embedded C code?

Tags: c, arm, stm32, microcontroller

I recently took over an ARM Cortex M4 C code base from another engineer who unexpectedly quit the job.  As I was looking through the codes to understand what was going on, I came across several uses of for(;;) structure.  I understood it to mean an infinite loop, but is it advantageous to use this over while(1) or while(True)?  It's just strange to me why you would want to use an infinite for-loop structure when you don't want to have a starting and stopping condition.

Not sure whether I should leave it be or convert it to a while(true) structure instead.  I don't know what's going on at the lower level when you use for(;;) as the structure since, normally a for loop would keep track of the variable count.  In the past, when the counting variable like i is declared as an int16, you could have an index overrun when reaching 32,768 for a signed int 16.  Maybe for(;;) is just automatically gets substituted as while(1) anyway, so there's no memory overrun.

The firmware produced from this code had issues with unexpectedly stopping ("hanging up") after running for a long time (>4 months), but that could be from various other problems due to memory overrun somewhere else.  The codes don't seem to do memory management too well.  I don't see any memory clean-up or freeing up array after infinitely running the loop.  Anyway, I don't know whether for(;;) would contribute to this, but maybe it's better to use while(true) instead?

The compiler is IAR Workbench for ARM to compile the C code for STM32L4R9x chip.

Comment: There's no difference, pure style, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186809/endless-loop-in-c-c

Comment: Also if you don't recognise the meaning of `for(;;)` I suspect that you might be in way over your head. "I don't see any memory clean-up or freeing up array after infinitely running the loop." Because it's not a PC?

Comment: Since you have the compiler at hand, check the difference between the alternatives. I'm sure you will find none, presumed that optimization is enabled. -- A simple counter overrun makes no memory overrun. You need to index an array with the counter, and then you will access elements out of bounds commonly much earlier.

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: A most important difference is that `for (;;)` is one keystroke less than `while (1)`. Just kidding.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.  Very helpful to see the variety of answers. Also, I have never had anything I would consider way over my head since after all anything can be learned with enough given time.  Experts become experts from time and experience and with right questions and finding helpful answers you can get there too.  The most ignorant person seems to be the one that thinks he knows everything and everyone else is just too dumb.

Comment: I also found a possible memory leak issue.  True, it's not a PC but it's running FreeRTOS which has a dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @Patratacus freeRTOS has it but should not be used by you. malloc like functions very quickly lead to heap fragmentation on resources limited platforms like micro controllers

Comment: @0___________ I don't have a choice.  Someone else wrote the code with freeRTOS and it's dumped on me at this point.  The guy said it makes it easier to manage multiple tasks but to me it seems to add complications.  We might have to re-do it since the program isn't stable after running for a long time.

Comment: I'll be running the FreeRTOS tracer to get a better understanding of the memory management issue.  Might be interesting to see what's going on. https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_Trace/FreeRTOS_Plus_Trace.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it advantageous to use this over while(1) or while(True)?

[No](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/94903).  Code for clarity<sup>*1</sup> and save your time for larger issues like "code had issues with unexpectedly stopping".

BTW: question has `while(True)` and `while(true)`.  Case is important in C and also *exactly* how was `True/true` defined?  Sticking with `for(;;)` avoids that issue.

> I don't know whether `for(;;)` would contribute to this,

It does not contribute.

---

Tip: Posting code is far more informative that only describing code.

---

<sup>*1</sup> Best to follow your group's coding standard.

Comment: *"while(True) and while(true)"* `while(1)` makes it easier

Comment: @0___________ Such preferences of `while(1), while(true), for(;;)`, etc. devolve into a [holy war](https://wiki.c2.com/?HolyWar).  As with such style issues, a group will have a living coding standard in which to guide the selection and save programmers time for bigger issues.

Comment: I prefer `while(true["or false"])` myself :)

Comment: @Lundin `while(true["or false"])` --> Practice for the [IOCCC](https://www.ioccc.org)?